# GitHub pull request show All checks failed after a very minor commit

Tags: github, jenkins, sonarqube, git-commit, pull-request

GitHub integrates jenkins and SonarQube:
My git commit showed the following issue as detected by sonarQube:

```
Rename this field "GSON" to match the regular expression '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. rule
```

To resolve this I made a very minor commit, I just updated a variable name from GSON to gson as required by sonarQube, but it says checks failed:

[image]

The checks tabs says there are no checks to run, there is also no option to rerun checks.

How can I resolve this issue ? Can i use the rebuild option ?

Can this happen if one build was in progress and i committed another one?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer to my question. It was a compilation error. I missed a line in commit.